# How do I group by on calculated columns?

Tags: sql, group-by

Assume the following table with 3 numeric fields:

```
Images (table)
--------------
Width
Height
Amount
```

Width and Height are image sizes in millimeters. Now I want to create a report about the amount of images grouped by their dimensions in centimeters. This means that I have to GROUP BY 2 non existing columns.

I can do:

```
SELECT      ROUND(Width/10,0)   AS W
        ,   ROUND(Height/10,0)  AS H
        ,   SUM(Amount)         AS A 
FROM        IMAGES
GROUP BY    Width
        ,   Height 
ORDER BY    W
        ,   H
        ,   A
```

but this will do the mm to cm conversion only on the view level and will result in more than one row for same dimensions.

e.g.

```
 W   H  A
--- --- - 
150 159 2
150 160 1
```

will not result in 1 category

```
W  H  A
-- -- - 
15 16 3
```

but in

```
W  H  A
-- -- - 
15 16 2
15 16 1
```

The targeted engine is actually a FileMaker database, that unfortunatly does not seem to support aggregate functions within the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 8):

Simply `GROUP BY` your calculated columns:

```
SELECT 
    ROUND(Width/10,0) as W
    ,ROUND(Height/10,0) as H
    ,COUNT(*) as A -- You may replace this with SUM(Amount) too
FROM 
    IMAGES
GROUP BY 
    ROUND(Width/10,0)
    ,ROUND(Height/10,0)
ORDER BY 
    W
    ,H
    ,A
```

**EDIT:** Also, from what I understand of your question you want the `COUNT` not the `SUM` of the rows..., right?

Comment: +1 : Or...  Replace `FROM IMAGES` with `FROM (SELECT ROUND(Width/10,0) AS W, ROUND(Height/10,0) AS H, Amount FROM IMAGES) AS data`.  Then you can `SELECT W, H` and `GROUP BY W, H` and `ORDER BY W, H` and know that all references to `W, H` always refer to the derived columns, and not have to repeat your calculations.

Comment: Works with mysql but not in FileMaker. It seems that FileMaker neither allows funtions in GROUP BY nor tables from subqueries :(

Comment: @mselbach Can you create table variables in FileMaker? What about temporary tables? In that case this may be a 2-step operation where you create the divided-by-ten values first, then aggregate them afterwards

Answer (score 2):

Following query uses `Common Table Expression (CTE)` to convert width and height from mm to cm along with rounding and then produces a derived table output. This CTE output is then used to group the width and height values to calculate the SUM of the amount column.

I am not sure if you were looking for `SUM` of the amount column or the `COUNT` of the amount column. I assumed *SUM* based on your query. If you only want *COUNT*, please change *SUM* in the query to *COUNT*.

[**Click here to view the demo in SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a8eec/1)

*Script*:

```
CREATE TABLE images
(
        width   INT     NOT NULL
    ,   height  INT     NOT NULL
    ,   amount  FLOAT   NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO images (width, height, amount) VALUES
    (150, 159, 1),
    (150, 159, 2),
    (150, 158, 1),
    (150, 159, 3),
    (150, 158, 2),
    (160, 158, 4),
    (160, 158, 1);

;WITH imagesincm AS
(
    SELECT      ROUND(width  / 10,0)    AS W
            ,   ROUND(height / 10,0)    AS H
            ,   amount
    FROM        images
) 
SELECT      W
        ,   H
        ,   COUNT(amount) AS A
FROM        imagesincm
GROUP BY    W
        ,   H 
ORDER BY    W
        ,   H
```

*Output*:

```
W  H  A
-- -- - 
15 15 9
16 15 5
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution. I see that this would be the approach with real sql databases but in FileMaker it just does not work. The SQL subset of filemaker is too limiting :(

Answer (score 0):

As per page 11 of the official FileMaker SQL Reference (https://help.claris.com/en/sql-reference.pdf) the Group By clause only works on fields.